# how do i display a random image after an animation?

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, animation, sdk

so im trying to make a rock paper scissors app activated by either a button or the accelerometer by first doing a short animation which cycles through the three, then display a random image  (1 of the 3) at the end of the animation. The animation itself works perfectly fine, but after it finishes the random image does not show.

```
UIImageView *image;
int x = arc4random() % 3 + 1; 
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.jpg", x];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're not initializing your `UIImageView`. Also, for the random image, I recommend this code: (it's more flexible)

```
    NSArray*images = rockpaperscissorsView.animationImages;

    NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random() % [images count];

    UIImage*randomImage = [images objectAtIndex:randomIndex];

    UIImageView*image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:randomImage];
```

Don't forget to release `image` once you're done with it.

Comment: No problem! If this is the answer you were looking for, mark it as accepted by clicking on the green checkmark icon. Welcome to the community!